# Find maximum between two rows, column wise

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm a newbie in R, trying to figure out how to find the maximum value between 2 values in a single column.

Example data:

```
t min most max
---------------
1 10   20   40
2 5    10   30
3 14   28   60
4 40   75   150
```

Result I'm looking for:

```
t min most max
---------------
1 10   20   40
2 14   28   60 
3 40   75   150
```

I have tried using rowWise(), but it's not working. I am getting the maximum value row wise using:

```
df$new <-pmax(df$min, df$most, df$max)
df
```

which gives me the maximum value for the entire row.

```
 t min most max new
-------------------
1 10   20   40   40
2 5    10   30   30
3 14   28   60   60
4 40   75   150  150
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? Are you essentially looking for a way to get `c(max(x[1], x[2]), max(x[2], x[3}, max(x[3], x[4]), ...)`, doing the max of every two adjacent values in a column vector?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `pmax` applied to the vector against its shifted self. Putting it in a nice little helper function:

```
adj_max = function(x) {
  pmax(x[-1], x[-length(x)])
}

as.data.frame(lapply(your_data, adj_max))

# or with dplyr
your_data %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), adj_max))
```

Reproducible demo:

```
x = c(10, 5, 14, 40)
adj_max(x)
# [1] 10 14 40
```